# Prevent smart contract deployment using parameter to constructor

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm using *hardhat* with *ethers.js* library and I noticed parameters to constructors are passed during smart contract deployment and **not** during instantiation of the contract. Also, on missing an argument to the constructor of my smart contract, the deployment failed.

Now, I have a hard coded key that must match the argument passed to my smart contract constructor like this:

```js
constructor(string memory authKey) {
    if(keccak256(byte(authKey)) != keccak256("&65I_am_a_sample_hard_coded_key&#£@"))) {
        // do not deploy (or just fail)
        // or at least, invalidate this contract
    }
}
```

I'm using the key check as a form of authorization.

Is it possible to prevent deployment (if possible, fail as when no argument is passed) if the passed key argument doesn't match my hard coded key? If not, can the smart contract be made invalid if the wrong key is supplied as argument during deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the revert command like this:

```
revert(‘Reverted due to bad constructor parameters’);
```

or instead of an if clause you could just do:

```
require("condition", "Reverted due to bad constructor parameters");
```

and the third option (this one is used when something critical goes wrong, as it consumes all transaction gas:

```
assert("condition");
```

So contract creation transaction is just like any other and the constructor is just another function, which is called upon deployment, so the same rules apply here as they would in the case of a normal function.